# How to call uploadBytes and then addDoc in Firebase by sequence

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

Consider:

```
await addDoc(inventoryCollectionRef, {
    ...inventoryFormData,
    content: "test1",
    region: User.region ? User.region : "Global",
    author: User.username,
    roleId: User.roleId,
    auditState: 0,
    publishState: 2,
    createTime: Date.now(),
    star: 0,
    view: 0,
  }).then(() => {
    message.success("Inventory successfully added", 5);
  });

await uploadBytes(imageRef, upload[0]).then(() => alert("image uploaded"));

.then(() => {
    message.success("Inventory successfully added", 5);
  });
```

I want to call the addDoc and then uploadBytes by sequence. After both of these function calls are completed, then only display the success message. May I know how I can do it?

Updated for answer and the question is solved
Here's the updated code with the structure change that is working now. I did remove all the Promises and replaced them using .then(). You can call uploadBytes() first and then use .then() to call addDoc().

```
const saveInventory = () => {
  try {
    const inventoryFormData = inventoryForm.getFieldValue();
    const addInventoryDetailsFormData = addInventoryDetailsForm.current.getFieldValue();
    const upload = addInventoryDetailsFormData.upload;
    console.log(upload);
    if (upload === undefined) {
      delete addInventoryDetailsFormData.upload;
      addDoc(inventoryCollectionRef, {
        ...inventoryFormData,
        ...addInventoryDetailsFormData,
        createdTime: Date.now(),
        region: User.region ? User.region : "Global",
        createdBy: User.username,
        roleId: User.roleId,
        imageURL: null,
      })
        .then(() => navigate("/app/inventory-manage/list"))
        .then(() => message.success("Inventory successfully added", 5));
    } else {
      const imageRef = ref(storage, `images/inventory/${upload[0].uid}`);
      uploadBytes(imageRef, upload[0].originFileObj)
        .then((snapshot) => {
          return getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref);
        })
        .then((downloadURL) => {
          delete addInventoryDetailsFormData.upload;
          addDoc(inventoryCollectionRef, {
            ...inventoryFormData,
            ...addInventoryDetailsFormData,
            createdTime: Date.now(),
            region: User.region ? User.region : "Global",
            createdBy: User.username,
            roleId: User.roleId,
            imageURL: downloadURL,
          })
            .then(() => navigate("/app/news-manage/draft"))
            .then(() => message.success("Inventory successfully added", 5));
        });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

I removed all the promise calls.

Comment: Check out Promise.all (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all?retiredLocale=de) which returns an array of the results for the promises if you await it.

Comment: Is your `uploadBytes` depandant of `addDoc` ? or they can run in parallel

Comment: They can do it in parallel

Comment: Hi Timon I have tried the method from the mozilla, seem like it is working for me. I updated the code, can you take a look is it correct way?

Comment: @Marcus You just have to remove the `await` keyword in front of `uploadBytes` and it will be ok. And if you just want a message when both asynchronous operations are done you can remove `then(() => alert("image uploaded"))`.

Comment: Hi @Marcus does the comment made by Renaud Tarnec helped you if so then post answer as other community members will also get the answer for this question.